# viで複数ファイル間のコピー＆ペーストを行うには？

Tags: vi

viではyyなどでコピー、pでペーストできますが、別のファイルにペーストしたい場合はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vi ファイルA ファイルB(複数ファイルを同時に指定する)

yyもしくはyw(コピー)

:n（次のファイルに移動） 
:rew（前のファイルに移動）

追加したい場所で、 
p

以上で、別ファイルにコピーできます。

Answer (score 1):

既に`vi fileA.txt`と`vi fileB.txt`という感じで別々に開いていて、fileA.txtからfileb.txtへコピーしたい場合です。
fileA.txtを開いているviで<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>という感じでyankして、fileB.txtを開いているviで<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>とすると実現できます。